# Is questions about playback on topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Is questions about playback, playback tools / equipment on topic?

Comment: I don't know what this question is asking. Can you elaborate, please?

Comment: I mean questions like "What tool i.e. commuter or CD player is recommended to use when playing sound effects in a theater?"

Comment: live sound questions are on topic - see [the FAQ](http://audio.stackexchange.com/faq)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean general questions about hi-fi, then the answer is probably not (unless you are asking about listening to your recordings on consumer devices as part of the mixing process).

If you mean questions about studio monitors / headphones then yes they are on topic.

**Update** According to the [FAQ](http://audio.stackexchange.com/faq), live sound engineering questions are on topic too, so your example of a question about playback in theatre is fine.

Comment: I agree, it depends on application.